# SpringToolSuite 2.9.2 not working with Android plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins

I've been using **STS 2.9.2** and tried to install the **Android Eclipse plugin** from

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.

I am using Windows XP.

This plugin gets installed successfully and then I've restarted STS many times (using **-clean** as well).

But Android is not showing up anywhere; I've tried:

1. Window->Preference, or
2. File->New, or
3. File->New->Other.

I can see Android only in the 'installed plugins' list.

- Does this plugin works with STS 2.9.2?
- Why it says installed successfully when i don't even see it anywhere?

I've also tried to

**uninstall Ardroid Plugin** -> **clean STS restart** -> **install plugin** -> **clean STS restart**

But it still not shows anywhere.

thanks,
Adi